# How install Tex-live on Ubuntu Kylin not showing on Software?

Tags: 16.04, texlive, kylin

How do I install Tex-live on Ubuntu Kylin if it isn't showing up on Ubuntu Software?

Answer (score 0):

You could open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and run:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

There is no hyphen in the package name.